# Mysql is saving date 1 day earlier date that provided from input from java application

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat8

I am using following specifications in my current project (production)

1. OS: CentOS 7
2. Database: MySql
3. Java 8
4. Hibernate
5. tomcat server 8

The database is in separate server than application server but both are in same LAN.

Datatype in mysql table is: `date` for storing date only and `datetime` for saving date along with time.

The problem is mysql saved every date 1 day earlier than the date provided from applcation. I have tried the following till now but still no luck:

1. I have set timezone for both application and database server as Asia/Dhaka and checked this from my java application too.
2. I have also set timezone in tomcat server (setenv.sh) file.
3. I have also checked the generated sql from hibernate by TRACE in log4j properties file where the date is also same as input date.

What am I missing? Can anybody suggest?

Comment: Your Application and DB server are in same Timezone ?

Comment: @MyTwoCents: yes, both are in Asia/Dhaka timezone

Comment: May I suggest a typo mistake... as it is easy to set a wrong date in the first place, DB being exactly one day late... (and install `ntp` client to ensure the date and time are correct)

Comment: @RingØ: I have selected the date from datepicker UI and it's showing correctly in my controller code. Thanks for `ntp` client suggestion

Comment: Exactly 1 day earlier? Or 6 hours earlier?

Comment: @Nick: for date, it is 1 day earlier, for time: it is 6 hours earlier

Comment: What is your data type?

Comment: @Nick: one is `date` and another is `datetime`.

Comment: It definitely sounds like something is shifting your values to UTC (that would be the 6 hour difference). That was where I was going with asking about data types but MySQL only shifts values for `timestamp` data values, so it's not to blame.

Comment: You have not provided enough information. Edit your Question to specify the column data types, show your Java code, show your JDBC/SQL code, and show inputs and outputs.  Tip: (a) **Always use *java.time*** classes, never `Date`/`Calendar`/`Timestamp` etc. classes. (b) **Never rely on default time zone**, always specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly by passing optional arguments.

Comment: @Nick: Can you please explain or give some link about UTC time. should i need to change my data type from `date/datetime` to `timestamp`?

Comment: No you shouldn't change your data types. What you are using should be fine.

Comment: The treatment of time at Java, JDBC and the RDBMS are 1) different and 2) complicated. I would suggest you do some reading around these aspects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all for sharing your experience regarding the issue.

At last, I solved it by changing the `serverTimezone` attribute of mysql connection string in `dispatcher-servlet` of my java web application.

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://x.x.x..x:3306/dbname?characterEncoding=utf-8&amp;useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=Asia/Dhaka" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try changing the `serverTimezone`:

```
serverTimezone=GMT%2B8
```