# Sequelize bulkCreate() saves previous day

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I am using `"sequelize": "^5.8.6"`, `10.1.39-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution` and I am running, `node --version v10.15.3`.

I am trying to save the following array of json in my db:

```
dataArray = [{
  "name": "Product 1",
  "rating_date": "8/16/2019",
  "producer": "producer 1",
  "action": "Sell",
  "previous": "Buy",
  "to": "Sell",
}]
```

When saving the above array with `bulkCreate()` it looks like the following in my mysql db:

{
     "id": 3,
     "name": "Product 1",
     "rating_date": "2019-08-15T22:00:00.000Z", // <--- THIS DATE IS WRONG!
     "producer": "producer 1",
     "action": "Sell",
     "previous": "Buy",
     "to": "Sell",
  }

My sequelize definition looks like the following:

```
  const Product = sequelize.define('Product', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    rating_date: DataTypes.DATE,
    producer: DataTypes.STRING,
    action: DataTypes.STRING,
    previous: DataTypes.STRING,
    to: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {});
```

Any suggestions why the previous day is saved instead of the exact given date?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: It seems to be timezone issue

Comment: @NeelRathod Thx for your fast reply! How can I disable the timezone when doing bulk create. I would simply like to save the day as it is.

Comment: The field stored in db is datetime

Comment: And you passed only date

Comment: Did you try like passing a string like this . `rating_date": "2019-06-08 00:00:00" `

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473215/mysql-is-saving-date-1-day-earlier-date-that-provided-from-input-from-java-appli This might help in your issue